# Using lambda expressions by value capture

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

Quick query regarding usage of lambda captures, particularly about "by value capture". Here is my code:

```
class carl{
public:
    int x;      
    void sayhi();
};


void carl::sayhi(){

    auto c1 = [=](){            //capture by value
    std::cout<<&x<<std::endl;   
    x = 10;                     // access the copy?
    };

    c1();
    std::cout<<&x<<std::endl;   // same address as the one inside lambda
    std::cout<<x<<std::endl;    //prints 10 now WHY????
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

carl x;
x.sayhi();

return 0;
}
```

My issue is that, are "by value" captures in lambda supposed to affect the original? aren't they supposed to make a copy? From my example, I used `[=]` so my lambda will make a copy of the variable within that class's scope. I tried accessing `x` and it directly altered x's original value. I tried researching about it and from my own words: it's stated that accessing a variable inside a lambda which has a `[=]` capture will access the lambda's local copy.

Edit: I actually get the feeling that I am trying to access `this` pointer which is also captured from `[=]`. Therefore, accessing `x` from my code is like accessing `this->x` which is the same pointer as my original one. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are accessing non-static class data members inside lambda, you are actually capturing `this` pointer by value and accessing the class member as `this->x`. That means that no local copy of `x` is made. You are modifying the actual `x` in the current object.

If fact, if some value is really captured "by value", as a copy, an attempt to modify it will fail. The `x = 10` would not even compile if `x` was really captured by value. You need to declare your lambda as `mutable` if you want to be able to modify the captured state.

Comment: I see so my guess is right, would it be safe to assume that using `[=]` inside a class will allow me to directly access it's local members(no copies will be made)? so it makes no difference compared to using `[&]`  then?

Comment: @Carlo Brew: `this` pointer is a special case in lambda capture context, as any guide on lambdas will tell you. And with it, class members access also becomes special - you are laways accessing them as if "by reference".